# Loading UserControl programmatically using web.config control references

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty familiar with loading user controls programatically, however i would like to use the references set in the web.config rather than the `<%@ Reference %>` declaration on the page.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="uc" tagName="Menu" src="~/App_Controls/MainMenu.ascx" />...
```

How do i programatically load this control on my page using the web.config reference, not a path or register declaration.

```
        Control uc = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrol/WebUserControl1.ascx");
        plhStatCounts.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Thanks

Comment: You mention programmatically adding a user control, but programmatic user controls do not need to make use of the @Reference section or the web config, so are you planning on defining the user controls statically?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the [PagesSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.aspx) from web.config, then access its [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.controls.aspx) collection.

For example example:

```
    // Open the config
    Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("");

    // Retrieve the section
    PagesSection pages = (PagesSection)webConfig.GetSection("system.web/pages");

    // Find the control you are interested in, then load it
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
    }
```